# How to disable checkbox inside gridview?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

Hi I am developing one application. I have one multiselect dropdownlist box. Whenever i select one value in dropdownlistbox corresponding value in gridview will be having checkbox in below gridview. I want to disable that checkbox. I am basically mvc developer and finding hard times to fix this. I am trying my level best to fix this. For example, whever i select some value in dropdown I am getting ID using jquery as below.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.limitedNumbSelect2').change(function (e) {
        var selected = $(e.target).val();
    }); 
});
```

This is my gridview.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gdvRegretletter" CssClass="tableform" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Vendor_ID"
        EmptyDataText="No records found !" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" AllowPaging="true" OnPageIndexChanging="gdvRegretletter_PageIndexChanging">
        <Columns>
 <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="true" HeaderText="Select All">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="checkAll" runat="server" Text="Check All" onclick="checkAll(this);" />
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkselect" runat="server" onclick="Check_Click(this)" />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="id" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("Vendor_ID")%>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <HeaderStyle Width="8%" />
                <ItemStyle VerticalAlign="Top" Width="8%" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Username">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblUsername" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Username") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email Id">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Email") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
 </asp:GridView>
```

Whenecer i select some value from multiselect dropdownlist box I get id in a variable selected. As soon as I get ID in a variable selected i want to disable that checkbox in gridview. May i have some suggestions on this! Thank you all

Furthur i tried as below.

This is jquery code to hide checkbox

```
 $('.limitedNumbSelect2').change(function (e) {
 selected = $(e.target).val();
`$(".disablechk[Text='selected']").prop("disabled", true);`
```

This is my checkbox code inside gridview.

```
  <asp:CheckBox ID="chkselect" runat="server" onclick="Check_Click(this)" Text='<%#Eval("Vendor_ID")%>' class="disablechk"/>
```

I am trying to do whenever i get some value from dropdown slected i want to disable that particular checkbox.

Comment: What you are getting in selected variable. Is it single value or multiple values like array or comma separated string?

Comment: Thank you, It is multiple value sepearated by coma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are getting comma separated string then split it and make an array

```
var temp = new Array();

temp = selected.split(",");
```

then loop through it

```
$.each(temp, function( index, value ) {
    $(".disablechk[Text='" + value  + "']").prop("disabled", true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop the GridView HiddenField values and disable the checkbox accordingly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.limitedNumbSelect2').change(function (e) {
            checkGridView($(e.target).val());
        }); 
    });

    function checkGridView(selected) {
        $('#<%= gdvRegretletter.ClientID %> input[type="hidden"]').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == selected) {
                var checkbox = $(this).prev();
                checkbox.prop("disabled", true);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```